# How do I undo a git rebase after I've git push origin +master?

Tags: git

So I've done a git rebase of the last 10 or so commits.  Hit some merge conflicts, thought I resolved them.  Turns out, i resolved them wrong and now there is a build error.  I want to undo the git rebase, but I've already made my commit and git push origin +master to rewrite history.  Is it even possible to undo my git rebase at this point?  I've tried git reflog, but even the history there has been rewritten when I look at the HEAD id's.  I tried checking out about 18 different HEADs at different points of the git reflog, and all of them either have the new build error i introduced, or are so far back they have none of the changes from the last 10 commits in them.  Help and thanks

Comment: A rebase rewinds commits, sets a new head, then replays the commits on top of that head. The history as it stood before the rebase no longer exists. My advice would be to revert to the commit that you rebased your 10 commits onto or trudge forward and correct the build errors manually. I hope someone comes along with a better answer for you.

Comment: Revert the commit then do a `git reset --hard HEAD~10`, then add the correct commits.

Comment: do you work alone, or could there be others which could have pushed something you have overrode. what you need then to check is the reflog at the server. if you have shell access here or it is gihub then it is possible

Comment: Thank you for your comment guys. Git reflog did not seem to do it.  Instead, I was lucky another developer had the version of the branch before my rebase disaster on her local, and she pushed that up as the latest commit, and we continued from there.

Answer (score -1):

Use $ git reflog

For documentation, use $ man git-reflog

Always use git pull --rebase before push.